# How to reference into a different volume

Tags: back-referencing

My large lecture text is almost ready, and it has become so large (6 chapters, 450 pages), that I decided to subdivide it into 3 volumes of 2 chapters each, each with its own Title page, TOC, LOF, Nomenclature and Index. The problem is not the subdivision itself, since I made a structure file, which calls the chapters and subchapters. However, I am referencing for example in  chapter 5 (= chapter 1 of vol. 3 in the new layout) back to an equation in chapter 2 (= chapter 2 of vol. 1 in the new layout). My question is: **Is there a way to keep those references?**

I could do it by hand via a \cite[My Book, vol. I equ. nn]{xx}  command, but this makes it quite unflexible: since it is the first edition, all vol's might still change in the future.

I  looked at the Part command, but it only says that it does not make an entry in the TOC. Does it do something else and might that be a possibility?

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.
Angelika

Answer (score 2):

I found it. For all who have the same problem:
The Latex packages xr and/or xr-hyper seem to do the job.

Fuzzy